# Jquery Remove Attributes from element (in loop) only work the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a function that create and removes all data-attributes from 18 images elements (#scelta1, #scelta2, etc) it will run every time the user click one of these images:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#scelta6']").on("click", function() { 
    // For simplicity #scelta6,
    // the real function gets the id based on the element you click
    $('#scelta6'+).attr({'data-a': foo,
                        'data-b': bar,
                        [a lot of data-] });
    // All the variables is taken from the dropdowns choices of the user in a 
    // separate function
[do something]
    var conta = 1;
    var fiamma;
    while (conta < 19) {
        fiamma = $('#scelta'+conta);
        $.each($(fiamma).data(), function(i){ $(fiamma).removeAttr("data-" + i); });
        console.log(conta); // Just to know if the function is running 
        conta++;
    }
}
```

Now the problem: on a fresh new loaded page if I click on one these elements the function above will run without any problem and removes all the data-attributes from all elements. When I will click again on one of these elements all the all the data-attributes remain in their place! 
Why this function works only for the first time?
I missed something?

**EDIT**
The data will be removed in every element if the first time the function run and have in ALL the elements the data set.
For example: 
I will set data to #scelta1, #scelta2, #scelta3, the run the function, it will remove the data from all. Then I set again it in #scelta2, click and all the data will be removed. Then I set again data in #scelta1, #scelta2, #scelta3, click and all the data will be removed from them all. But if I set data to #scelta2 and #scelta4 it will remove ONLY the data in #scelta2...

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] and show us a working snippet?

Comment: `$("#scelta6']")` id name was wrong and inside the loop `i` is undefined,]. you  are added the iteration from `conta`

Comment: @prasanth the first time the function run work like a dream, the iteration is on conta and will run on every $('#scelta'+conta) for that reason, the i is the array index of the matched data-*, so it will take the name of data-* and remove it, but I can't find the reason for the odd behaviour on a second, third, forth call

Comment: the line `$(fiamma).removeData();` seems to be the guilty one here. Apparently, once removed with this line, jQuery doesn't find the data attributes anymore in `$.each($(fiamma).data()`, and so cannot delete them. I can answer the snippet i made with corrections if you like. (edit: and more, this line is not needed to actually remonve the attributes)

Comment: @Kaddath I know, the removeData() it's only for data(), cause it set data-* in che "cache" of  jquery, I've added it just for scruple.
To the downvoter: please tell me why you've done it...

Comment: i don't understand your last comment, if you know that `removeData` is the guilty one, why ask the question? And if you know that you don't need it for your current functionality, why add it?

Comment: @kaddath Cause it don't work with it, and don't work without it!

Comment: check my answer, it seems to work without it, as long as you don't click the "(with removeData)" button, it adds and delete all right. Note: i corrected various syntax errors in your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: it seems that using `attr` to set `data` attributes was causing the bug (i verified and the behaviour was like you described). With setting the attributes with `data()` it seems to work all right.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    //setting data with attr seems to be the cause of the bug here, use data() instead
    $('.sceltaButt').on("click", function() { 
      //$('#' + $(this).attr('id')).attr({'data-a': 'foo', 'data-b': 'bar'});
      $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).data('a', 'foo').data('b', 'bar');
      showData();
    });
    
    //then you don't need to remove them manually anymore, removeData is enough
    $('#removeData').on("click", function() {
      var conta = 1;
      var fiamma;
      while (conta < 7) {
          fiamma = $('#scelta'+conta);
          $(fiamma).removeData();
          //console.log(conta); 
          conta++;
      }
      showData();
    });
    
    //now this version doesn't work anymore because we use data()
    $('#removeWithoutData').on("click", function() {
      var conta = 1;
      var fiamma;
      while (conta < 7) {
          fiamma = $('#scelta'+conta);
          $.each($(fiamma).data(), function(i){ 
            $(fiamma).removeAttr("data-" + i);
          });
          //console.log(conta); 
          conta++;
      }
      showData();
    });
    
    function showData(){
      var result = '<br>';
      $('.sceltaButt').each(function(){
        /*$.each($(this)[0].attributes, function(){
            result += ' ' + this.name + ':' + this.value;
        });*/
        $.each($(this).data(), function(name){
            result += ' ' + name + ':' + this;
        });
        result += '<br>';
      });
      $('#result').html(result);
    }
    
    showData();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="sceltaButt" id="scelta1">ADD TO 1</button>
<button class="sceltaButt" id="scelta2" data-c="test">ADD TO 2</button>
<button class="sceltaButt" id="scelta3">ADD TO 3</button>
<button class="sceltaButt" id="scelta4" data-d="test2">ADD TO 4</button>
<button class="sceltaButt" id="scelta5">ADD TO 5</button>
<button class="sceltaButt" id="scelta6">ADD TO 6</button>
<button id="removeData">CLICK ME TO REMOVE (with removeData)</button>
<button id="removeWithoutData">CLICK ME TO REMOVE (without removeData)</button>
<div>CURRENT DATA: <span id="result"></span></div>
```

Comment: It works for a single element, it have to iterate through 18 different element that can have data-* or not, with or without removeData() it works for me too on a single element, the first you choose in the first time you choose it. Every time you will click on that element it's all ok, but when you click (for the second time) on another element, it keeps data- as the rest of the others element.

Comment: i edited my answer, the use of `attr` to set the data seems to be the cause

Comment: I've checked for different "try", I've edited the question, take a look

Comment: i don't understand your edit, this last version seems to work, even if i add data attributes beforehand in the html..

Comment: It seems to be the solution, I have to change all the attr with the data, it's a pain... but I don't get how attr can be the cause

Comment: it seems you have to use either `attr` or `data`, but not mix the 2, i don't know why this behaviour. Maybe you can just change this `$.each($(fiamma).data()` by `$.each($(this)[0].attributes` if you want to keep attr with the "removeWithoutData" version, i haven't tested.

Comment: No, I can't, if I use attributes it will remove the id and the src, by the way, thanks, now it works!